# Vim not updating lines in quickfix windows under under Cygwin

Tags: vim, cygwin

I have Vim 7.4 and it has a strange issue in a quickfix window when using Vim in Cygwin.

When moving downwards, everything if fine. When moving upwards, however, once my cursor is on the top of the window (not the top row), from then on every movement upward only updates the row one row below my cursor gets updated; the rest don't.

By pressing Ctrl+L and refreshing, the rest of the file gets updated properly. But the fix doesn't stay.

What is causing this and how could I fix it?

Facts:

- `TERM` is `xterm-256color`
- Mouse support works. This isn't quite relevant except it should demonstrate that vim, tmux and my terminal emulator are all configured fairly well in general.
- This happens even with an empty .vimrc
- The terminal emulator I am using is MinTTY
- Trying to reproduce it doesn't work. It happens in my Tmux session with 10 tabs open. But when I try to open another MinTTY with Tmux, the issue doesn't happen
- When trying to record the issue with Asciinema, the issue still comes up, but when looking at the recording, the issue is not seen there.
- One of the symtoms are that while using Vim, sometimes the contents of the lowest row (tmux tabs) are copied to vim's lower statusline row until the next full redraw of the screen.

Comment: Which terminal do you use, and what's the value of `$TERM`?

Comment: Added it to the new "facts" section

Comment: Again, what terminal? Do you just use the `Cygwin Bash` entry from the Start Menu, or PuTTY, or what?

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice that question. I added some more info.